# Sitecore Branch Template go to the first item in the hierarchy

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, routes, sitecore

I am working on a Sitecore project; I have a Branch template called Ballot which has two children: Entry and Thankyou, see below.

```
Ballot
   Entry
   Thankyou
```

Every time I create a Ballot item in my content tree; I can choose the name  of the Ballot. However, by the conventions of Branch templates I automatically get provided an Entry and Thankyou page.

```
SeaLife
   Entry 
   Thankyou
```

Currently on my application in order to View the Entry page; the User has to visit this URL:

```
http://blah.co.uk/pl-iw-test/SeaLife/Entry
```

What I would like to do is instead is configure the routing so that the User can type the below link in order to view the Entry Page:

```
http://blah.co.uk/pl-iw-test/SeaLife/
```

If anyone has any idea of how I can configure the routing for this Sitecore/ C# project, any help or advise would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To show one page by different URLs you can either [configure Sitecore aliases](http://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2013/08/sitecore-item-alias-alternate-url.html) or use [IIS rewrite rules](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Answer (score 0):

It seems your top level `Ballot` branch item is just a container or folder for your content.

The simplest solution is to change your branch templates in order to support the content structure you require rather that fighting the framework and adding code solutions where it is not needed.

[image: Ballot Brnach Template]

You can then redirect the user to the "Thank You" page afterwards as you currently do.

Comment: Hi JammyKam, thanks for your answer.                                                                                             The Ballot page; is basically a container/folder however it has it’s own data template as well.
When the User create a new branch template they should also be able to enter custom information about that Ballot